# I am getting "NoReverseMatch" error for my 'results' page

Tags: javascript, django

I am creating a quiz website. After the user answers all the questions he is redirected to the results page. But if he clicks the back button in Chrome he goes back to the questions in the quiz. But since the quiz is submitted i don't want him to go there. Instead It should redirect him into the home page where a list of all quizzes is available.

So in the templates of the results page I included the following JavaScript code.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        // Check if the referring URL matches the results page URL
        console.log('Referrer:', document.referrer);
        var expectedReferringURL = '{% url "quizquestions" %}';
        
        // Check if the referring URL contains the expected URL pattern name
        if (document.referrer.includes(expectedReferringURL)) {
            // Replace the current history entry with the home page URL
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, '{% url "quizlist" %}');
        }
    };
</script>
```

The url pattern of the name "quizquestions" is

```
    path('quizzes/<int:quiz_id>/question/<int:question_id>',user_views.quizquestions,name='quizquestions')
```

But when I go to the results page it shows this error

`Reverse for 'quizquestions' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['quizzes/(?P<quiz_id>[0-9]+)/question/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']`

Any thoughts on why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the setup of your project you have to specify the `app_name` within the url-statement

```
{% url '<app_name>:<view_name>' %}
```

Most likely you defined the app name within urls.py:

```
app_name = 'quizzapp'  # app_name
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

The second problem you'll be facing is that you need to pass two integers to that url. Otherwise it can not be resolved. That view needs `<int:quiz_id>` and `<int:question_id>`. You can add these as kwargs or args like this:

```
{% url "quizzapp:quizquestions" quiz_id=5 question_id=19 %}
```

Within the error it says: "Reverse for 'quizquestions' ***with no arguments*** not found". Therefore pass the arguments as I showed above.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) you'll find more examples.